# Как в laravel правильно работать с фронтенд файламы (javascript, css, sass)?

Tags: php, laravel, frontend, laravel-mix

Как  правильно работать с фронтенд файлами , хранить их в папке resources  или  в папке public ,  нужно ли все файлы соединить в одно (app.js, app.css) и минифицировать ?

Интересует любая информация и ваш опыт работы с фронтендом в Laravel ?

Если есть ссылки  буду рад посмотреть ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что вам не ясно? В папке `resources` хранятся ваши исходники. Там вы делаете всё так, как хотите. Там же и разрабатываете. В `webpack.mix.js` описываете правила минификации этих файлов в папку `public`. Ну а дальше просто по обычной логике. Если что-то используется пользователем на каждой странице, то лучше это объединить в один файл. Пример: ваши скрипти и стили для пользовательской части сайта и для админки. Ежу понятно, что объединять вместе их не имеет смысла, но вы можете. Нет запрета. В общем, исходите из банальной логики. Ну самое простое - разбивка скриптов на пользовательские и админские.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял то изначально все  css  и js  должны находится в папке `resources` , и в коде   уже изначально должны использовать только минифицированный скрипт `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: ну да. Идите лучше курсы проходить. Вот замечательные курсы для начала. Есть субтитры. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7FQEutaCiQ&list=PLl_kpL5cwH6LLuvd_xXOplXejM7shFhme&index=1

Comment: **Ну самое простое - разбивка скриптов на пользовательские и админские.** Что значит админский скрипт , это скрипт плагинов или скрипт  админ панели ?

Comment: Это то, что понадобится только в админ панели. Только для человека, который зашёл в админку. То, что обычному пользователю сайта не нужно

Comment: Если соединить все пользовательские и админ скрипты например(`admin.min.js` , `website.min.js`)  и поставить их в шаблон blade,  скажется ли это на производительности сайта, ведь каждая страница имеет свой набор  нужных скриптов а тут мы каждой странице даем `website.min.js`

Comment: Если всё соединить в одно, то увеличится время загрузки. И объём загрузки, т.е. расход трафика. Блин, я не понимаю ваших вопросов. Это же очевидно. Если у вас пару админов, то смысла объединять нет, т.к. все скрипты понадобятся только паре человек, а для обычных пользователей это лишний трафик, лишний мусор. Если же у вас почти все заходят в админку, то объединяйте. Это же очевидно.

Comment: Спасибо, только я не имел ввиду  соединение `admin.min.js` со `website.min.js`  -ом,  логично что этого делать не надо,  вопрос был в том , если использовать  bundle  файл  `website.min.js` во всех пользовательских страницах,  правильно ли это будет с точки зрения производительности (или это не существенно) .

Comment: лучше объединить всё в одно. чем меньше запросов, тем лучше.